# Grabbing a database as JSON using a lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm using dynamo-db scan to get this a database table in JSON format, but it seems to not be working

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

dynamo.scan({ 'TableName' : 'DATABASE_NAME' }, function(err, data) {
    console.log('this doesnt print');
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
    else console.log(data);
});
context.succeed('ding');
```

I don't believe it is entering the callback function at all, since 'this doesnt print' doesn't print. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show how do you run this?

Comment: is your `exports.handler` function even called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `context.succeed()` before the DynamoDB call finishes. You need to look into how asynchronous calls work in NodeJS. Try something like this:

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

dynamo.scan({ 'TableName' : 'DATABASE_NAME' }, function(err, data) {
    console.log('this doesnt print');
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack)
      context.fail(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(data);
      context.succeed('ding');
    }
});
```